# Get RFH2 usr area name-value pairs from MQ queue using Java

Tags: java, ibm-mq, loadrunner

Using Java, I want to build a MQ message that has MQMD,RFH2 usr area (with few name-value pairs). 
I am able to connect to Qmgr and able to read a message from one queue. 
I want to retrieve all header values (MQMD,RFH2 usr etc) and build one such message based on the retrieved message
Can anyone please help me out in this ?

FYI: I am doing a load testing using Loadrunner tool that puts loads of messages on inbound queue and they will be processed and will be sent to outbound queue. And the tool will read the current queue depth of the outbound queue to check the total processing time.

Any suggestion are welcome

Images :
[MQ Message headers Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npHQT.png)

[Unsupported Version at MQRFH2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEmOE.png)

Answer (score 0):

About handling the MQ headers using the Java classes for MQ you should read this:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030880_.htm

To solve your requirement I think it is enough to use the MQMD.
What I'd do is recording the PutTime and the MsgId of the input message from the MQMD, and the put time of the corresponding output message. (I hope the CorrelId is set to the input MsgId by your application for the response messages.) By calculating the elapsed time between the put times you get the time the message spent in the queue and the processing application.

Comment: I have read the page you had linked . But there is not even complete Java example to build a message with MQMD and RFH2 headers and send to queue. 
Moreover, I am sending about 200K messages and i cant open one message and check its time because like that i have to go to each destination queue and check their times. I think you are doing in functional testing if am not wrong

Answer (score 0):

MQRFH2 header can be thought of as a state of mind.  You can have message properties with or without an MQRFH2 header.

There is a queue attribute called [PROPCTL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.mig.doc/q008230_.htm).  You can read about it [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.mig.doc/q008230_.htm).

From your Java code, just do:

```
MQMessage msg = new MQMessage();
msg.setStringProperty("propName", "propValue");
```

or if you want to get really fancy, then use the MQRFH2 class.

```
MQMessage msg = new MQMessage();
MQRFH2 rfh2 = new MQRFH2();
rfh2.setFolderStrings(new String[]{"<d1>First</d1>", "<d2>Second</d2>", "<d3>Third</d3>"});
MQHeaderList putList = new MQHeaderList();
putList.add(rfh2);
msg.format = putList.updateHeaderChaining(CMQC.MQFMT_RF_HEADER_2);
```

Personally, the first example is far easier and cleaner but hey, that's what I prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Roger
Both options you provided me did not work either
I am trying to build a MQ message with the headers like in the image attached above in the post 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/npHQT.png

Comment: If you want the extra folders (i.e. mcd, psc, jms & usr) then use the 2nd method.  You will need to play around with the code and you could probably skip MQHeaderList as you are only using 1 header.

Comment: thanks Roger for the reply.
When i add your code snippet in my code , I am getting an error

**java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/ibm/mq/internal/MQCommonServices : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 

I am using Java\jdk1.6.0_37 and also used jars from Websphere MQ. Please see the link below http://i.stack.imgur.com/QEmOE.png